# How to avoid ConcurrentModificationException on sorting ArrayList

Tags: android, kotlin, exception

I am randomly getting an ConcurrentModificationException on the following piece of code :

```
fun sortAppListByLabelName()
{   
    Logger.debug("sortAppListByLabelName", "called sorting app list by label name")
    appsList.sortBy { it.label.toString() }
}
```

with appsList being an ArrayList

```
private val appsList: ArrayList<AppInfo> = ArrayList()
```

The error being thrown is the following

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1472)
   at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:201)
   at r6.p.q(MutableCollectionsJVM.kt:1)
   at r6.j.q()
   at ****.****.****.sortAppListByLabelName(AppAdapter.kt:3)
   at ****.****.****.populateLauncherItems(Launcher.kt:18)
   at ****.****.****$populateAndRefreshCoroutine$1.invokeSuspend(Launcher.kt:4)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.a.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:3)
   at j7.o0.run(DispatchedTask.kt:22)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.a.E(CoroutineScheduler.kt:1)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.a$c.c(CoroutineScheduler.kt:4)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.a$c.m(CoroutineScheduler.kt:4)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.a$c.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:1)
```

I am not sure what the exact issue is, is this because this is done within a coroutine ? Or is there some other foul at play ?

This happens on several Android versions, the crashes that have been logged were both on Android 9 and Android 11 devices.

/edit :

> can you add the code where you add elements to the ArrayList

```
fun addApp(app: AppInfo) {
    if(appsList.any{ it.label == app.label})
    {
        VBLogger.debug("AppAdapter","addApp() NOT executed for ${app.label}")
    }
    else //add
    {
        appsList.add(app)
        VBLogger.debug("AppAdapter","addApp() executed for ${app.label}")
    }
}
```

The whole workflow is as follows

```
suspend fun populateAppItems(){  
   val allApps: List<ResolveInfo?> = mPm.queryIntentActivities(i, 
   PackageManager.MATCH_ALL) //retrieves installed apps, which then is iterated through 
   for (ri in allApps){
      if(executingLauncherItemsAndRefreshNotifications!!.isActive) {
         fun addPackage called // adds single packages to ListAdapter
         fun ListAdapter.AddApp called // see other code snippet
      }
   }
   fun sortAppListByLabelName called // see other code snippet
}
```

The interesting part though is that the above workflow is encapsulated by this function :

```
private var executingAppItemsAndRefreshNotifications : Job? = null //variable holding our adapter update Job so that we can cancel it

private fun populateAndRefreshCoroutine()
{
    Logger.debug(TAG,"Entering populateAndRefreshCoroutine()")
    executingLauncherItemsAndRefreshNotifications?.cancel()     //cancel existing job if ongoing
    executingAppItemsAndRefreshNotifications =
            launch() {
                populateAppItems()
                sendRefreshNotificationBroadcast()
            }
}
```

Comment: can you add the code where you add elements to the ArrayList

Comment: You are modifying the array (adding/removing elements) while the sort is in process. Better to avoid ArrayList and use Kotlin `List` and `list.sorted()` function to sort it.

Comment: @ArpitShukla if i'm not mistaken ArrayList inherits from MutableList which is an interface to a List so I was in the assumption that any thread-safe functionality would apply for ArrayList as well ?

Comment: @Kaido added the requested code in the original posting above

Comment: @ArpitShukla also when you say it's better to use List and list.sorted() how would that be implemented ? I should replace the Arraylist with mutableListOf?
And the sorted() method returns a List itself, should then the original appsList in this case be overwritten by this returned List ?